# Add a TextView to move with Images in slide using ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

Hey I'm relatively new to Java. So far I have an activity where images can slide, pinch to zoom, and have page dots moving with the image in sync. I want to add a TextView that goes with each specific image underneath the images so they slide in sync with each other. To be clear; I want a different textview with each image that slides. How can I achieve this?

**Edit: Found a solution - Check my answer below!**

Here's the main class i'm using:

```
public class Location2Images extends AppCompatActivity {

ViewPager viewPager;
LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
private int dotscount;
private ImageView[] dots;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_location2_images);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
    dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

    for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++) {

        dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
        dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

        sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

    }

    dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {

            for (int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++) {
                dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));
            }

            dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}

}
```

And here is where I created a class for PagerAdapter:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Integer[] images = {R.drawable.image2a,R.drawable.image2b,R.drawable.image3a};

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, final int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    PhotoView imageView = (PhotoView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(view, 0);
    return view;

}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);

}
}
```

And here is my main xml layout:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
    android:layout_width="125dp"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_marginTop="206dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.502"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.37"></LinearLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="349dp"
    android:layout_height="296dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.545"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.023" />
```

And last my custom xml layout for the images (used PhotoView Library for zoom):

```
    <com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />
```

As I said I'm new to Java so any code edits would help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using Fragments with a pager adapter? Might get you closer to what you want

Comment: @cricket_007 do you have a good example? I looked into fragments but couldn't get it to where I could do everything i'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: I don't have examples, no. So, you have to array of images, why can't you add in an array of strings that correspond to those?

Comment: @cricket_007 that sounds like it would work but as I said i'm new to java and actually not sure how to do that. If I add: private String[] texts = {"text1", "text2", "text3"}; below the image array what else would i have to do to make them correspond to each other?

Comment: The same location of `imageView.setImageResource`, you'd need to add a TextView and set the text

Comment: @cricket_007 I'm not sure what you mean? I added the text/string array under the image array. Do i make a textview in the main xml or the custom xml. and after that i'm not sure what to do...

Comment: In the `custom_layout`, add a TextView, `findViewById` for the it (like you already did for the PhotoView), then just call setText on it... It's really not that complicated

Comment: @cricket_007 I got what your saying. I did that and it works for a small amount of text. The problem is I was looking for a way to make the text a textview with scrollable text. When I have a really large string (which I do in some cases) the text goes off the screen. Any idea what I could do? Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome to put a ScrollView around the TextView or change the size of the font depending on the length of the string

Comment: @cricket_007 LOL totally forgot I had to do that. Coming from xcode where a textfield scrolls automatically. That worked. I appreciate your help! I think I made this problem more complicated then it actually was...Again thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@cricket_007 helped me out. This was easier then I made it out to be. For anyone looking at this wanting to know you can reference my code... Just add the following to get text with the image slide:

An array of strings under my array of images:

```
private String[] texts = {"text1", "text2", "text3"}
```

Define the id of the text (from the custom xml layout):

```
TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

And finally set the location under my images location:

```
textView.setText(texts[position]);
```

Also obviously remember to add a textview in the custom xml layout

Answer (score 0):

Go to you "custom xml layout" and add a Linear/ Relative Layout as parent. Put your "PhotoView" code in that layout and add a text view in that layout as well.

Your Custom XML layout will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.appslume.currencyconverter.MainActivity">

<com.github.chrisbanes.photoview.PhotoView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/hello_world"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:textSize="50sp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now access your textview in your adapter with it's id and use it however you want to use.

Comment: Thanks @ZohaibHassan. I want to be able to have different text for each image that slides. How would I do that?

Comment: You have to follow few steps, first step is to access your textview in your adapter class "instantiateItem()" method like this:

    TextView imageView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.hello_world);

Comment: Second step is that you have to change your array type from "int" to a custom class type which will be having both "image id" and "text string".

Comment: And you have to set that text to your text view like this:
textView.setText(array.get().getItemTitle)

Comment: But you must know how to create a "Model" class, if you dont then search for "how to create custom ArrayList in android?".